# How to prevent matplot from cycling through line styles?

Tags: r

How can I stop matplot from cycling through different line styles? Right now I'm attempting the following code two ways:

```
matplot(cbind(c(1,3,7,3), c(2,4,4,7)), type=c("l","l"), col=1)

matplot(cbind(c(1,3,7,3), c(2,4,4,7)), type="l", col=1)
```

And even though I am trying to tell it explicitly to only use line graphs, it also cycles through all types of dotted lines, as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just specify the line type, `lty`:

```
matplot(cbind(c(1,3,7,3), c(2,4,4,7)), type="l", col=1, lty=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the argument `lty`

```
matplot(cbind(c(1,3,7,3), c(2,4,4,7)), type="l", col=1, lty = 1)
```